# Get count of cells in column where sum of those cells are less than a specified value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jXWkwZbxAkaYHFT4slzSmIMP23AaubTjjtDuYX7myp8/edit?usp=sharing) where I am trying to get the count of cells in a column, where their sumproduct value reaches a specified number (I wrote comments on the spreadsheet that should make it clearer).

So far I have got some sort of formula, but it is returning me the total count of all cells in the range a specify? I cannot figure out how to do this, so any help would be much appreciated.

My formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(sumif(SUMPRODUCT(AB13:AB,if($X$13:$X<>"",1/$X$13:$X,1)),"<="&AB13:AB167,AB13:AB167),"<="&abs(AB9)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my copy of your sheet. It's set to "anyone can edit".
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ebu7UNCVuG7DyC4kVGLiRr3AT4vyU2V_lwlnALQfGy4/edit?usp=sharing

This is the formula I came up with.  It gets rid of the need for the row count column you have.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(F11,MMULT(N(ROW(F13:F)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(F13:F))),IFERROR(F13:F/MMULT(N($F13:$H<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($F13:$H)^0)),0))))
```

It will be a little slow with very large sheets.  You'd need a different solution if you were going to have more than a couple thousand rows.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I copied your formula over to my full dataset and it works a charm - you saved me many more hours of trying to solve it! I only plan to have 365 days worth of rows so the formula is still fast